# AMD radeon 7570 powering 2 monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi, dvi

I have a Dell XPS 8500 -  I have enabled intel multi display in the bios. I am running monitor 1 via DVI-D (monitor) to DVI-D (Radeon board)  I would like to run my 2nd monitor via DVI-D (monitor) to the board's HDMI connection and have the cable to do so.

Both monitors are recognized upon boot up and I have a dual display, but then Monitor 2 is seems to be recognized as VGA (with no display on the monitors screen) upon complete boot into windows 7, see [picture at this link](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/19517255.aspx).

If I remove monitor 1 and only boot up with Monitor 2 connected, windows does not recognize the monitor and I have a blank screen. I have tried another cable (DVI-D to HDMI) and the results are the same.  What else can I do to trouble shoot this problem and determine why Windows is not recognizing the second monitor as a digital display? FWIW the 2nd monitor is a dell 2007WFP and the monitor is set utilize the DVI-d connection and goes into power save when Windows is completely booted up.

Well it seems like the 2nd monitor is not being recognized at all. if I unplug the 2nd monitor I get [the same detect screen as shown here](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/19517255.aspx) and I am not able to change display options on first monitor at all which makes sense if I don't have a 2nd monitor.  I do believe the HDMI port is operational (at least to a degree) because when I have both monitors plugged into the card, upon bootup I have a dual display, it's when Windows 7 loads that the HDMI monitor is not recognized at all.

Comment: It would be easier to run both from the card

Comment: Why the setting `show desktop only on 1`?

Comment: I am running both from the card.. the card only has hdmi and dvi-d - my first monitor is running correctly configured as dvi-d from the card to dvi-d to the monitor, my second monitor is running hdmi from the card to dvi-d on the monitor but windows is not recognizing the 2nd monitor as digital and for some reason wants to think it is vga but I get no screen. Does the HDMI to DVI-D cable not work as digital with the 7570 board?

Comment: Please register your user account and then have your accounts merged. See: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 XPS 8500

- click Start
- Bottom of Start Menu type in "two monitors"
- Search Results → Set up computer to use multiple monitors
- Plug in both monitors (1)DVI & (1)HDMI
- Click DETECT

B.T.W. you should set the `multiple displays` to `extend these displays`.

Comment: I have done as instructed above and get this for the setup.. it wants to see the HDMI connection as VGA: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/19517255.aspx  I can't set the multiple displays to extended because windows will not allow me to modify any settings for the 2nd monitor

Comment: In my setup with a xps8500 i **need** to change the `multiple displays` to `extend these displays` (and apply) **first** before i can change the setting on the second display. What does windows give you (screenshot) if you choose `extend these displays` and apply or is that option not available in the dropdown?